# Error while configuring build server on windows server 2012

Tags: configuration, tfs, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to create build definitions for a project. TFS and build server machines are the same.

When I create the build definition using Default Template (Tfvc Template.12.xaml ), it gives the following error:

```
Exception Message: The path '$/Scrumproject/Scrumproject/Scrumproject.sln' could not be converted to a local path. Make sure this path is relative to the 'src' folder on the build machine or specify a full server path. (type ArgumentException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Core.LocalPathProvider.GetLocalPath(String incomingPath)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

When I use the Upgrade template it gives the following error:

```
Exception Message: TF42006: The build service could not get the project file for build definition Newdefinition. Ensure the project file exists and the build service account NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE is a member of the Build Services group for the team project. (type InvalidBuildTypeException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Can anyone help configure the build server correctly?

Comment: In which moment do get those errors? Trying to create a Build Definition or they came from a queued Build?

Comment: @GiulioVian they come from a queued build. I have successfully created build definitions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first error could be due to an incorrect mapping: is $/Scrumproject/Scrumproject/ folder mapped in the build workspace?

Comment: Source control folder is -**$/Scrumproject/Scrumproject/MvcApplication1** The build agent folder is **$(SourceDir)**

Comment: You need to go one step up with the mapping
like $/Scrumproject/Scrumproject/ otherwise the Build cannot locate the .sln file.